# Laravel 5.2 Model Relationships

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

im new to Laravel and have a relationship question.

The goal is to get all News where `news.page_id = page.id` AND `page.pagetype_id = pagetype.id` WHERE `pagetype.component = news` AND `page.app_id = 1`

```
class News extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'news';
    protected $fillable = ['page_id', 'title', 'description', 'active', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
}

class Page extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pages';
    protected $fillable = ['app_id', 'unique_id', 'pagetype_id', 'title', 'picture_url', 'short_description', 'description', 'valid_since', 'valid_until', 'extras', 'active', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function pagetype() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PageType', 'pagetype_id');
    }
}


class PageType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pagetypes';
    protected $fillable = ['pagetype', 'component', 'active', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function page() {
      return  $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Page', 'pagetypes', 'id', 'id');
    }
}

// now i need   All News Items where page.pagetype_id = pagetypes.id and patchtypes.component = news

// First Attempts are

Page::whereHas('pagetype', function ($q) {
            $q->where('component', 'news');
        })->where(['app_id' => 1])->get();

// result is all Pages which has the proper component news.
```

This is what i have tried yet, but in my attempt i'll only receive the proper pages but of course not the news.

My "current" solution is to get all the pages and then loop through `News::where('page_id', $myPageId)`. But im pretty sure its possible to get a proper relationship to get also news.

I cant do any other model since there are many different pagetypes and components aswell.

Thanks so far.

Comment: Im not  sure if this is the proper way but it looks like to work:
    News::whereHas('page', function ($q) { $q->where('app_id', 1); })->with('page')->get();

News Model:
      public function page() {       return  $this->hasMany('App\Models\Page', 'id', 'page_id');    }

Comment: You also can do it with leftJoin like so: `News::leftJoin('page', function($q) { $q->on('news.page_id', '=', 'page.id'); })->leftJoin('pagetype', function($q) { $q->on('page.pagetype_id', '=', 'pagetype.id'); })->where('pagetype.component', 1)->where('page.app_id', 1);`

Comment: Can you post your schema

Comment: Check the fillable since those are almost the whole schema (except the id which has auto increment, unique)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add relationship function to news model.

```
public function pages() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Page');
}
```

And call it through `News` model.

```
News::with('pages')->where('app_id',1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off all I think that you are wrong with you `PageType` relation

```
class PageType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pagetypes';
    protected $fillable = ['pagetype', 'component', 'active', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function page() {
      return  $this->hasMany('App\Models\Page');
      // if i understood you correctly you haven't got any pivot table
    }
}
```

Then you should link your `News` and `Page` like so

#### News.php

```
class News extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'news';
    protected $fillable = ['page_id', 'title', 'description', 'active', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
    public function page() {
      return  $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Page');
    }
}
```

#### Page.php

```
class Page extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pages';
    protected $fillable = ['app_id', 'unique_id', 'pagetype_id', 'title', 'picture_url', 'short_description', 'description', 'valid_since', 'valid_until', 'extras', 'active', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function pagetype() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PageType');
    }

    public function news() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\News');
    }
}
```

Then  you can achieve your goal

```
News::whereHas('page', function($q) use($appId) {
    $q->where('app_id',$appId);
})->whereHas('page.pagetype', function($q) {
    $q->where('component', 'news');
})->get();
```